# Передача атрибутов при запуске из командной строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Основная идея заключается в том, что нужно сделать такой код, который был бы "гибким" при изменении или введении новых атрибутов.

Пример:

```bash
#python main.py -start -i -config="config.json" -no-log
```

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста. Вам надо передать атрибуты из командной строки в скрипт?

Comment: Именно так.
Предположительно, их нужно будет использовать по ходу работы скрипта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае, есть объект `.argv` из библиотеки `sys`, в котором будет размещено все, что Вы введете в командную строку через пробел.

```
import sys

for param in sys.argv: 
    print(param)
```

Если Вы, например введете, что-то типа:

```
#python main.py -config new_config.json
```

То, каждый из набора символов, разделенных пробелами: `main.py`, `-config` и `new_config.json` будет лежать как строковое значение в `sys.argv[0]`, `sys.argv[1]` и `sys.argv[2]` соответственно. Обратите внимание, что в `sys.argv[0]` всегда лежит имя запускаемого скрипта. Таким образом, Вы можете использовать эти параметры для изменения поведения Вашего скрипта.

Но разбирать такую строку ужасно неудобно, поэтому есть более удобные модули, например, `argparse`. Вам лучше почитать [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), это достаточно мощный инструмент.

Но, в общем случае это выглядит как-то так:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # определяем объект ArgumentParser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # добавляем параметр, который мы ожидаем на входе из командной строки
    # повторяем эту строку по количеству параметров
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--config_file', type=str, help='Name of the config file', default='config.json')

    # в этот объект попадут все разобранные параметры
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(args.config_file)
```

Теперь, когда Вы введете в командную строку

```
#python main.py --config_file new_config.json
```

или

```
#python main.py -c new_config.json
```

то в свойстве `args.config_file` окажется `new_config.json` и Вы его используете.

Остальное в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) там много всего.